# ASP.NET MVC Redirect

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I work on one of my first ASP MVC-programs at the moment. 
The program should show me a list of product, and with a link beneath the name of the product it should be possible to edit the product. No problem so far.

```
@model MVC3Demo.Product

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
}

<h2>Edit</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm("Save", "Product"))
{
<div>
    <input type="hidden" id="ID" name="ID" value="@Model.ID" />
    ProduktID @Model.ID
</div>
<div>
    Produktname <input id="Name" name="Name" type="text" value=@Model.Name />
</div>
<div>
    Preis <input id="Price" name="Price" type="text" value=@Model.Price />
</div>
<div>
    <input type="submit" value="Speichern"/>
</div>

}
```

Now I have written a `Save` action method that should update my data:

```
    public ActionResult Save(Product p)
    {
        ProductRepository rep = new ProductRepository();
        rep.Update(p);
        return RedirectToAction("List");
    }
```

The "List"-View is where I can see all products with the edit-link.
The problem is, that if I press the save-button, it redirects me to the old list, not to the updated one. I debugged my project and I´m sure that the update-method works correct and updates the product.

My `List` action is:

```
@model IEnumerable<MVC3Demo.Product>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "List";
}

<h2>List</h2>

<ul>
@foreach (MVC3Demo.Product p in Model)
{
    <li>@p.Name @Html.ActionLink("bearbeiten", "Edit", "Product", p, null)</li>  //new{ ID = p.id}
}
</ul>
```

Because you asked, here is the `List` Action:

```
    public ActionResult List()
    {
        ProductRepository rep = new ProductRepository();
        return View(rep.GetAll());
    }
```

So where could be my mistake?

Comment: can you post your List Action?

Comment: I'm guessing that the updated data is not being saved in the database. Have you verified the data at the database level?

Comment: I don´t have a database, I just hava a List<Product> and I´m sure that it is saved there.

Comment: can you post code for List Action? as public ActionResult List {}

Comment: @Harald - The List<Product> is your problem. It will not be persisted between requests.

Comment: Sorry, it´s a IList<Product>, but how can I solve the persist-problem?

Comment: you can use TempData to pass data between Controllor Actions

Comment: Passing Data in an ASP.NET MVC Application - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd394711.aspx

Comment: What exactly does your ProductRepository do if it's not saving to the database?

Comment: You need to show us your repository code.

Comment: your data is not saved, try to use rep.Savechange or rep.AcceptChanges in stad of rep.update(p)

Comment: Are you sure `List` doesn't come from any cache? (browser or .net)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're calling the update, but you're not actually submitting the transaction itself, does your repository have a SubmitChanges, AcceptChanges or Commit or something similar? As with DataTables, your changes won't actually take effect (save to the database) until you call AcceptChanges.

Answer (score -1):

Try include an `HttpPost` attribute at `Save` controller method.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Save(Product p)
    {
        ProductRepository rep = new ProductRepository();
        rep.Update(p);
        return RedirectToAction("List");
    }
```

Comment: I think Your Save method is not saving the results in the database. So in that case it doesn't update the list.

Comment: Please use back-ticks for `inline code` in both your own posts and when you make edits to other people's content.

Comment: You would only need HttpPost if both the Get and the Post methods were named the same.

Comment: +1 I think you're right it should be an `HttpPost`. Requests done via `GET` "SHOULD NOT have the significance of taking an action other than retrieval". Part of the HTTP specification! http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616 Section 9.1.1